# Is odl-l2switch broadcasting packets?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, openflow

I created a simple fat-tree topology using mininet. I am using opendaylight controller with **odl-l2switch-all** feature installed. I am pinging only two hosts in my topology. When checking the open-flow rules on the edge switches, I noticed that the rules are forwarding packets to all other ports (4-port switches are used in the topology)

```
 cookie=0x2b00000000000013, duration=138.581s, table=0, n_packets=56, n_bytes=4760, priority=100,dl_type=0x88cc actions=CONTROLLER:65535
 cookie=0x2b00000000000007, duration=133.161s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=2,in_port=3 actions=output:4,output:1,output:2,CONTROLLER:65535
 cookie=0x2b00000000000008, duration=133.161s, table=0, n_packets=251, n_bytes=112196, priority=2,in_port=4 actions=output:3,output:1,output:2,CONTROLLER:65535
 cookie=0x2b00000000000009, duration=133.161s, table=0, n_packets=435, n_bytes=65519, priority=2,in_port=1 actions=output:3,output:4,output:2
 cookie=0x2b0000000000000a, duration=133.158s, table=0, n_packets=2, n_bytes=214, priority=2,in_port=2 actions=output:3,output:4,output:1
 cookie=0x2b00000000000013, duration=138.581s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, priority=0 actions=drop
```

I was expecting the l2switch to be more specific using the Mac-learning for the paths, Am I missing any configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are running with [proactice-flood-mode](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/user-guide/l2switch-user-guide.html#configurable-parameters-in-arp-handler)?

Comment: I found that is enabled by default, thank you so much

Comment: Do you know how exactly l2switch feature will decide the path between any source and destination? It is mentioned that it is using Dijkstra, is that true?

Comment: I don't think it's using Dijkstra. Someone brought this up on the mailing lists recently. see here: https://lists.opendaylight.org/pipermail/l2switch-dev/2018-April/001464.html